# Can Android 12 update trigger "new access" notification?

Tags: applications, updates, security

I recently got an e-mail warning that an app has been granted access from a nearby location, just after updating to Android 12. Device used was "app" not web browser.

I changed password and re-logged in. The location was the same, unfortunately IP address is not provided.

Could it be a false positive triggered by the Android update?
Should I be worried about any phone intrusion? To be clear, I do not download third-party apps, from unknown source and whatsoever.

Comment: The update didn‘t trigger it for me. I would also recommend putting what device this was on, and maybe checking any recently installed apps?

Comment: fishing e-mail?

Comment: You haven't mentioned which app and email source, so it's hard to give feedback of what really happened (you mentioned you don't download 3rd-party apps, but we don't know if the app and/or email itself is actually from the 3rd-party or not). Otherwise, I'd assume the email is from Google Account. Though Android updates don't do anything to the apps, other than possibly only updating some of the system apps.